# What's wrong with my gradient descent? (simple, one variable)

Tags: machine-learning, gradient-descent

```py
# calculating the cost function
theta = np.array([[0], [0]])
def h(X, theta):
    return np.matmul(X, theta)

def cost(X, y, theta, m):
    return 1/(2* m) * np.sum((h(X, theta)-y)**2)

print(cost(X, y, theta, m))
# 1-variable gradient decent
cost_vals = []
def grad_decent(X, y, theta, m, alpha):
    theta1 = theta[0, 0]
    theta2 = theta[1, 0]
    for i in range(0, iter):
        cost_vals.append(cost(X, y, np.array([[theta1], [theta2]]), m))
        theta1 = theta1 - alpha/m * np.sum((h(X, theta)-y) * X[:, 0])
        theta2 = theta2 - alpha/m * np.sum((h(X, theta)-y) * X[:, 1])
        # print(f"Iteration {i}: ", theta1, ", ", theta2)
        
    return np.array([[theta1], [theta2]])
```

As one can see I'm doing gradient descent with only one feature, i.e. I want to fit a line of the form theta1 + theta2 * x to my data. I know that for such small feature sizes one would definitely use the normal equation, but I wanted to implement it with gradient descent. My learning rate alpha is 0.01 and I'm following the machine learning course of andrew ng on coursera. However, instead of converging, my cost values increase so there is some mistake in the algorithm which I can't find. X is of the shape 97x2 where the first column is just ones since there is only one feature but I want to fit a polynomial with two coefficients.

Answer (score 1):

You set your model parameters using `np.array([[0], [0]])`, meaning that your parameter array is of shape `(2, 1)`. Changing this to `np.array([0, 0])` (with shape `(2,)`) decreases the loss over time as expected using a learning rate $\alpha$ of 0.01. Looking more closely at the difference of using the two, I see that your way returns way higher losses (exactly 100x). Using a smaller $\alpha$, e.g. 0.0001, with your implementation also works:

[image]

Therefore the main reason of your implementation is your choice of $\alpha$, which is too high, preventing the model to reach the optimum.

**EDIT**: The issues is twofold, the first is indeed the shape or your `theta` array. The second has to do with the fact that you are using the `theta` array in your for loop which always contains the original `theta` parameters, as you are not storing and using the updated `theta1` and `theta2`. The following code seems to give a good result of $\theta_1 \approx -3.2$ and $\theta_2 \approx 1.12$ using 1000 iterations with $\alpha=0.01$

```
import numpy as np

# load and transform data
data = np.genfromtxt("data.txt", delimiter=",")
X = np.stack((np.ones(data.shape[0]), data[:,0]), axis=-1)
y = data[:,1]

m = X.shape[0]
iter = 1000
 
# calculating the cost function
theta = np.array([[0.3], [0.5]])
def h(X, theta):
    return np.matmul(X, theta)
 
def cost(X, y, theta, m):
    return 1/(2* m) * np.sum((h(X, theta)-y)**2)
 
print(cost(X, y, theta, m))
# 1-variable gradient decent
cost_vals = []
def grad_decent(X, y, theta, m, alpha):
    theta1 = theta[0, 0]
    theta2 = theta[1, 0]
    for i in range(0, iter):
        theta = np.array([theta1, theta2])
        cost_vals.append(cost(X, y, np.array([theta1, theta2]), m))
        theta1 = theta1 - alpha/m * np.sum((h(X, theta)-y) * X[:, 0])
        theta2 = theta2 - alpha/m * np.sum((h(X, theta)-y) * X[:, 1])
        # print(f"Iteration {i}: ", theta1, ", ", theta2)
        
    return np.array([[theta1], [theta2]])

grad_decent(X, y, theta, m, 0.01)
# 1740.4098044406999
# array([[-3.20070025],
#        [ 1.12320526]])
```

[image]

Comment: unfortunately that didn't change anything. I changed the learning rate as you proposed (I would have done that before but as I mentioned I'm following a machine learning course and coded the exact same in matlab before where a learning rate of 0.01 worked perfectly)

Comment: The [following code](https://pastebin.com/wpRi7wtA) works perfectly fine on my end. Can you try running this? It may have to do with the data you are training the model on. What scale is your data on, i.e. are they small or large values?

Comment: here is my data set, the first row denotes the input values and the second the desired outcome, and for formatting it you'd need to add another line of 1 to X: https://pastebin.com/fdecfLsc. So X = column of 1's and the first column of the data, y = second column of the data

Comment: I've updated my OP, I think this should solve the issue.

Comment: ouhh thanks how stupid, I just didn't store it correctly, thanks!

Comment: could you tell me why exactly the shape of my theta vector causes a problem? If I'm thinking about the problem mathematically dimensions 2x1 seem logical to me. Because if I'm using np.array([0, 0]) my cost function doesn't work since it's not a vector so matrix multiplication wouldn't make much sense if I'm not missing some point

Comment: @mathematicalinutition could you pls explain why reshaping the parameter array leads to the error decrease?

Comment: @Oxbowerce could you clarify why reducing my 2x1 vector to a 2x ? vector played such a big difference? Also, when putting np.array([theta1, theta2]) into the cost function, this doesn't yield correct results since the dimensions are incorrect, meaning if I put np.array([0, 0]) into the cost function it yields an incorrect value (3111) wheres is should be something like 32